# trouble with li.selected menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a `.selected` state to my navigation menu using jquery. I can see that it is trying to work, but after all is said and done, the style does not "stay". It should be white after it is clicked.

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="coolMenu">


  <li class="end"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
  <li class="mid"><a href="products.html">products</a>
    <ul class="mama">
        <li class="uno"><a href="http://www.preworkoutforwomen.com"
   onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.preworkoutforwomen.com']); return false;">Athena PreWorkout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

  <li class="midx"><a href="unico_fitness_blog.html">u.blog</a> </li>
  <li class="midx"><a href="unico_athletes.html">athletes</a></li>
    <li class="midx"><a href="aboutus.html">about us</a></li>
  <li class="midx"><a href="contact.html">contact</a>  </li>
  <li class="shop"><a href="http://mgfyb.pkhqw.servertrust.com/">shop</a>  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
#coolMenu {
    list-style: none; 
    float:left; 
    padding-left:7.5px; 
    padding-right:0px; 
    position:relative;
}

#coolMenu ul  {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #4a4a4a;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px #4a4a4a; 
}

#coolMenu .selected {
    background-position:bottom !important; 
    color:black !important;
}

#coolMenu li {   
    width:145px;
    height:48px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../images/misc/images/retina-sprite_03.png);
   -webkit-background-size: 750px 150px;
   -o-background-size: 750px 150px;
   -moz-background-size: 750px 150px;
   background-size: 750px 150px;
    background-position: -301px -1px;
   -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#coolMenu > li.end {
    border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:7px;
    border-top-left-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:7px;
    background-position: -601px -1px;       
    text-align:center;
}

#coolMenu > li.shop {
    text-align:center;
    border-left-style:ridge;
    border-left-color:#333;
    border-left-width:thin;
    border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:7px;
    border-top-right-radius:7px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:7px;
}

#coolMenu > li.mid {
    text-align:center;
    border-left-style:ridge;
    border-left-color:#333;
    border-left-width:thin;
}

#coolMenu > li.midx {
    text-align:center;
    border-left-style:ridge;
    border-left-color:#333;
    border-left-width:thin;
}

#coolMenu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2.4em;
    line-height: 2.1em;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#coolMenu uno,dos,tres a {
    display: block;
    height: .5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 0px;
}

#coolMenu ul li {
}

#coolMenu ul li a { 
}

#coolMenu li:hover ul.noJS {
    display: block; 
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#coolMenu li").click(function() {
        //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
        $("#coolMenu li").removeClass('selected, end, mid, midx, shop'); 


        //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
        $(this).addClass("selected");


       });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on links page is refreshed. Change them from :

```
<li class="end"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
```

to

```
<li class="end"><a href="index.html" onclick="return false"></a></li>
```

If you want to test without refresh page.

EDIT : you can also changeyour javascript file to :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#coolMenu li").click(function() {
             //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
             $("#coolMenu li").removeClass('selected, end, mid, midx, shop'); 


             //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
             $(this).addClass("selected");

             //CHANGED
             return false ;   
       });
});
```

Comment: I see that it works when i test using this method, however is there a way I can have this happen after the links are clicked through? It is my main navigation menu I would like the active page to have that class after the page is loaded...is this possible??

Comment: You can do this easly by adding css to a specific element of your page in html.

Ex : 
    `<style>
       .end a { color: white;}
    </style>`. But you have to specify different ID/Class by element. Indeed, css or js cannot be through by HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

It is because after click event the clicked page opens and reloads entire page. it is completely another page after the click.

I am not sure what you actually try to do but if your pages are html, you should set the `selected` class in html file

for product.html

```
    <li class="selected"><a href="products.html">products</a>
```

if you are load the content by JS such as displaying another div or load by AJAX.
You should use `event.preventDefault();` after the addClass function.

EDIT:
If you want to select class after load try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coolMenu li a").each(function () {
           if (location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1)
           {
                $(this).parent().attr("class", "selected");
                return false;
           }
     });
});
```

Hope it works I couldn t test it.

Comment: It is my main navigation menu so I am trying to have it display the 'selected' class when that particular page is open

Comment: so as I said you should change the HTML in the products.html by giving the selected class.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't in answer to your question as I'm pretty sure the other commenters have already covered that. I just want to say, I tidied up your CSS code because it was in a bit of a mess. Also you should always put the unprefixed CSS3 property under the prefixed ones (i.e `border-radius: 5px;` should go under `-webkit-border-radius: 5px;`), so that when the browser vendors drop the prefixed versions (most modern browsers don't use prefixes any more for a lot of CSS3 things, `border-radius` included. You should still include the prefixed versions for older versions of the browsers though.), the unprefixed versions will overwrite the obsolete prefixed versions.

Secondly, you don't seem to use shorthand CSS much, which can massively improve the effecieny of CSS. E.g `background: /* code */` can cover `background-image`, `background-position`, `background-size`, `background-color` etc. Read [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/shorthandproperties) for more info about Shorthand CSS.

Comment: Thank you for that Tom, appreciate the feedback! If you don't mind, could you offer a solution to the actual question? The code is for my main navigation menu, and I am trying to have the corresponding tab display the 'selected' state when that page is opened, so that you know what page you are on. Any ideas? I have seen this implemented in several websites before so I know its possible, I just cant seem to make it work! Thanks again for your CSS help